# C++ CURL not returning data on specific URL

Tags: c++, ubuntu, curl, cgi

I want to send CGI command to IP camera.
I send e.a. CGI url to receive camera name and the function returns the right name, so I think my code is fine.

When I send another CGI url from my browser, it is working (camera returns "ok") but when I try to send it with my program, my camera is not returning anything and parameters are not set in camera.

here is my code:

```
string data; //will hold the url's contents
size_t writeCallback(char* buf, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* up)
{   for (int c = 0; c<size*nmemb; c++)
    {
        data.push_back(buf[c]);
    }
    return size*nmemb; //tell curl how many bytes we handled
}


string send_CGI_command(string username, string password, string port, string URL)
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {
                curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL); //pretty obvious
                curl = curl_easy_init();

                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PORT , stoll (port,0,0) );

                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERNAME  , username.c_str());
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD  , (username + ":" + password).c_str());
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH  , CURLAUTH_BASIC);

                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, (URL).c_str());

                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &writeCallback);
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);

                curl_easy_perform(curl);
                curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
                curl_global_cleanup();                             

                return data;
            }
}
```

I use this command to request the CGI:

```
string result = send_CGI_command(get_video_login_cam1(),get_video_password_cam1(),get_video_port_cam1(),"http://" + get_video_ip_cam1() + "/cgi-bin/configManager.cgi?action=setConfig&Locales.DSTEnable=true&Locales.DSTEnd.Day=0&Locales.DSTEnd.Hour=3&Locales.DSTEnd.Minute=0&Locales.DSTEnd.Month=10&Locales.DSTEnd.Week=-1&Locales.DSTEnd.Year=" + std::to_string(1900 + ltm->tm_year) + "&Locales.DSTStart.Day=0&Locales.DSTStart.Hour=2&Locales.DSTStart.Minute=0&Locales.DSTStart.Month=3&Locales.DSTStart.Week=-1&Locales.DSTStart.Year=" + std::to_string(1900 + ltm->tm_year) + "&Locales.TimeFormat=dd-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss");  

    cout << endl << result << endl;
```

This is the debugger info:

```
*   Trying 192.168.1.14...
* Connected to 192.168.1.14 (192.168.1.14) port 80 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'admin'
> GET /cgi-bin/configManager.cgi?action=setConfig&Locales.DSTEnable=true&Locales.DSTEnd.Day=0&Locales.DSTEnd.Hour=3&Locales.DSTEnd.Minute=0&Locales.DSTEnd.Month=10&Locales.DSTEnd.Week=-1&Locales.DSTEnd.Year=2016&Locales.DSTStart.Day=0&Locales.DSTStart.Hour=2&Locales.DSTStart.Minute=0&Locales.DSTStart.Month=3&Locales.DSTStart.Week=-1&Locales.DSTStart.Year=2016&Locales.TimeFormat=dd-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.14
Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=
Accept: */*

* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host 192.168.1.14 left intact
```

I have no idea why my exact same CGI is working in browser and the exact same cgi does not returing anything with CURL. Like I said in beginning, another CGI command to get device name is working in browser and with same CURL code.

Thank you in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: So it works if you copy-paste the full request from the debugger information into a browser? If you compare the headers being sent from your cURL call and the browser, do they differ?

Comment: Sorry I did not replay more quickly. I will have a look into how it works with these headers. I used to program in c# so i think i need to do my homework better for learning cpp. I will keep you informed of my progress; thanks already for guiding me :-)